# Why was this admitted typo question disputed?

Tags: discussion

In this question: [React using external API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35300509/691711), the questioner admits that the whole basis of the question was caused by a typo since the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35300827/691711) boils down to:

> You have a type-o!
>
> You have AppAPI imported and using AppApi

I marked the question off-topic because it directly fits:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely
>   inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem
>   before posting.

Do reviewers not get to see the context for the question and why this <s>might be</s> is a typo?

Comment: This is all the reviewers saw: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11206199 . The answer isn't shown, so this would have to be visible in the comments or in the question itself for that to be determined.

Comment: @BradLarson posted his comment just before I posted my answer, but we're saying the same thing.

Comment: To be fair If I review a question and don't catch the typo before someone point it (in an answer or comment) I can give it a Ok too. **After** someone posting an answer point out the typo I cannot vote to close because someone deserved that "acceped" points. At the other side the question being a typo ill deserve a lot of downvotes and ill sink to the bottom of SO where it ill be almost harmless.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your flag was marked as disputed automatically [when the post cleared the Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11206199). In that queue, users only see four options:

- Looks OK
- Requires Editing
- Unsalvageable
- Skip

Critically, they don't see any answers to the question, so they wouldn't see how the question was resolved. This is actually a fine question in that it meets the site's standards. It just turns out to be caused by a typo, and only someone capable of answering the question (and really paying attention) would catch that.

The users who reviewed the question in Triage did so correctly. Unfortunately, that auto-disputed your flag. That's probably a design flaw, because the Triage review didn't really relate to the same issue that your flag addressed (the typo), but it's how it is.

Note that [when you hit 3k rep you can just vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). You won't have to raise a flag at all for an issue like this.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.  I agree that it looks like a good question.  Is this just a caveat of the Triage Review queue?  It doesn't seem like typo flags could even be resolved by that set of options without greater context.

Comment: @zero298 Unless I'm mistaken, all of the review queues are built this way. If a post comes out unscathed, or (in some circumstances) if a suggested edit is approved, certain flags get marked as disputed. In this case, the review queue in question and the flag reason don't match up very well. As you've probably seen, I voted to close the question at issue, because your flag was clearly correct.

Comment: @EdCottrell was the flag declined or disputed? Marking a flag as disputed is OK when there are conflicts like this, as disputed flags don't count towards you.

Comment: @Cristik It was disputed. That's still a problem, though: it may not hurt the flagger, but it results in the loss of a helpful flag.

Comment: @EdCottrell It would be better to set it as "aged away"? You still loss the flag but due to other reasons rather than being disputed, due to the flag review system not being fast enough

Comment: @Llopis That wouldn't really help. As you say, we'd still lose the fag, and the reasoning wouldn't make sense; it's normally impossible for flags to age away that quickly. It would be better if such flags weren't declined at all for this kind of reason.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I call provide a option "comment" to by "vote to close"/"flag to close" that is seen by people in the review queue.

Just the other day, I had to flag a question to the MODs, as I know a normal close vote would fail, due to the justification for the close being in an answer.

Comment: One option would be to add a comment to the question. The comment would be visible to reviewers, although it may be hard to spot if there are already many comments.

Comment: @Blackwood I'm always wary of changing posts even if they were to be deleted.  I barely clean true spam questions aside from whatever crappy links they have embedded in them even though I've seen posters obliterate whatever was originally there and replace it with say, "**SPAM**" or whatever.  I do that out of fear that robo-reviewers would just instantly mark it as "Attempt to reply" without even trying to pick up the comments context.

Comment: @zero298 I believe Ian was asking for a way to provide a comment when flagging/voting to close a question that could be seen by reviewers. My suggestion was to use the "add a comment" link on the question, not to edit the question.

Comment: @Blackwood Oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood.  That's a much better suggestion then.  Although I'd still worry that reviewers wouldn't pay the comments any mind.

Comment: @zero298 Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally nice to post a comment to the question you flag/vote to close/downvote/etc. It may help the OP with a clue on how to improve before his question receives a ton of downvotes or gets put on hold.

In this particular case, your comment would have given the triage reviewers a clue about the typo, so they might have voted to close as well.