# Why was my 'offensive' flag disputed?

Tags: support, disputed-flags, review-abuse, offensive-flag

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715214/what-are-the-major-benefits-of-codeigniter-3) as **offensive** and it got disputed. If the reviewer had no idea of what the OP was saying in then why dispute it ?

For the info OP is abusing to the people who will **downvote** his question in Hindi language.

Comment: Down voters care to comment please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can only handle flags if we understand them. The mere presence of a foreign language is not offensive, though it tends to make a post off-topic. Unless the moderator handling the flag knows the language in question, then, how are we supposed to know *what* is offensive?

If you need to flag offensive content in a non-English language, please use a custom flag (preferably with a translation). Most of the time, though, you don't even need to do that. Just edit out the offensive language. Unless the question is specifically *about* offensive speech in a non-English language, then the non-English, offensive part has no place on the site, anyway.

Also, please note: the reason your flag got disputed was actually due to the [Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11457263). As [I've explained elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316544/2057919):

> In that queue, users only see four options:
>
> - Looks OK
> - Requires Editing
> - Unsalvageable
> - Skip

For a question to be marked "unsalvageable," its offensive content would have to be pretty blindingly obvious and integral to the post, so it couldn't just be edited out. That's not the case in the post that you flagged. So, reviewers mostly marked it "requires editing," with the effect that your flag was marked disputed.

Comment: If the reviewer had no idea of what is being said by OP and it's flagged as offensive then he should pass it on.

Comment: @noob That's not how it works. You should only use that flag if "A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse." If a reasonable person who speaks the only language used for posts on this site *wouldn't know the post is offensive,* it's not really an offensive post for the vast majority of users. Also, the "offensive" flag gets horribly abused. Many if not most posts flagged "offensive" simply aren't. In any case, see my edit -- your flag was disputed not because someone saw your flag and disagreed but because of how the triage review works.